# Почему при замене символа я получаю NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

```html
import pandas as pd
data = {'kol_click':[1, 8, 4, 2, 1, '', 18, '', 3, 10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['kol_click_1'] = df1['kol_click'].str.replace('', '0')
print(df1.head(10))
```

```html
  kol_click kol_click_1
0         1         NaN
1         8         NaN
2         4         NaN
3         2         NaN
4         1         NaN
5                     0
6        18         NaN
7                     0
8         3         NaN
9        10         NaN
```

Почему числа поменялись на NaN ? Как заменить пустые строки на нулевые значения?

Comment: Думаю, вашу багу можно так повторить: `str(18).replace('', '0')`, получите `01080`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вызвана смешением целых чисел и строк в одном столбце. Pandas воспринимает тип такого столбеца как `object`:

```
In [17]: df1.dtypes
Out[17]:
kol_click    object
dtype: object
```

Но комфортно работать c таким столбцом как с обычным строковым столбцом не получится:

```
In [25]: df1['kol_click'].str[:10]
Out[25]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5
6    NaN
7
8    NaN
9    NaN
Name: kol_click, dtype: object

In [26]: df1['kol_click'].astype(str).str[:10]
Out[26]:
0     1
1     8
2     4
3     2
4     1
5
6    18
7
8     3
9    10
Name: kol_click, dtype: object
```

---

**Решение** - попробуйте так:

```
In [22]: df1['kol_click_1'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['kol_click'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)

In [23]: df1
Out[23]:
  kol_click  kol_click_1
0         1          1.0
1         8          8.0
2         4          4.0
3         2          2.0
4         1          1.0
5                    0.0
6        18         18.0
7                    0.0
8         3          3.0
9        10         10.0

In [24]: df1.dtypes
Out[24]:
kol_click       object
kol_click_1    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает